# How to ignore exceptions on delete if database id not exists anymore?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'd like to ignore any exceptions that occur during a delete action in spring `CrudRepository`.

```
@Tranactional
public void remove(Long id) {
    try {
        if (id != null) dao.delete(id); //CrudRepository
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ignore any exceptions, it's not critical delete
    }
}
```

Problem: when I run this, I'm still getting the following exception (eg if the id to be deleted does not exist anymore in database - means it may have been deleted concurrently). How could I ignore it?

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: This exception is not occurring during a delete action. The code you listed does not throw the exception you posted.

Comment: Well but the logs exactly point to that code line where `dao.delete()` is.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you catch the exception, the transaction manager will mark the transaction as rollbackonly, so when you commit at the end of the method you will have an `TransactionSystemException` exception.

The first reflex is to mark the method `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)` but this does not solve the problem because if you take a look in `SimpleJpaRepository` class wil see that `delete` method is marked as `transactional`, so when the exception is thrown, this `@Transactional` marks your transaction as rollback only.

In my opinion, the solution is to call `findOne` method and then if entity exists call `delete` method (call delete method by entity and not by ID) :

```
@Tranactional
public void remove(Long id) {
    if (id != null) {
     YouEntity entity= dao.findOne(id);
     if (nonNull(entity)) {
        dao.delete(entity);
     }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Tranactional(rollbackFor={TableNotFoundException1.class, RecordNotFoundException.class}
public void remove(Long id) {
    try {
        if (id != null) dao.delete(id); //CrudRepository
    } catch (Exception1 e) {
        throw new TableNotFoundException1();
    }catch (Exception2 e) {
        throw new RecordNotFoundException();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RecordNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

You have to find out how you catch `Exception1`, `Exception2` or just use `Exception` with `rollbackFor={Exception.class}`

Why need to declare `rollbackFor`? by default Spring rollbacks unchecked exceptions only.

Other option: 
Following will also work, but without using `@Tranactional`

```
//@Tranactional(rollbackFor={TableNotFoundException1.class, RecordNotFoundException.class}
public void remove(Long id) {
    try {
        if (id != null) dao.delete(id); //CrudRepository
    }catch (Exception e) {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: @andolsizied check the spring docs + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125837/why-does-transaction-roll-back-on-runtimeexception-but-not-sqlexception/7125918#7125918