# Why Grails/Spring transactional behavior not working in this case?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I have a grails (2.5.2) app, with a mysql and a NoSQL interaction. There's a main/principal service method that call 2 other methods:

```
class mainService {

  static transactional = false
  NoSQLDataAccessService noSQLDataAccessService

  // main/principal method
  @Transactional
  void save(json){

    // (1) creating domain entities from json
    addNewDomainEntities(entities)

    // (2)
    noSQLDataAccessService.set(json)
  }

  @Transactional
  void addNewDomainEntities(entities){
  // save the entities in a mysql schema and use save(flush:true) 
  // because i need the generated id's
  }

}
```

As you can see, this mainService creates new domain entities (1), flushing the session to get the id's. Then, i call other service method (2) that store the json in a NoSQL schema:

```
class NoSQLDataAccessService(){

  static transactional = false

  void set(json){
    try{
    // save the json in a NoSQL schema
    } catch(Exception ex){
      // if fails, i log the exception and throws it again
      throws ex
    }
  }
}
```

But, sometimes the noSQLDataAccessService.set() fails by external causes **and the entities created before still persist in the mysql db.(this is the problem)**

The save method, that contains all this program execution, is marked like @Transactional, so if the noSQLDataAccessService.set() throws an exception, all the changes made should be not applied because the rollback. I'm right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to throw an RuntimeException, not an Exception, to force a rollback as per [this StackOverflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125837/why-does-transaction-roll-back-on-runtimeexception-but-not-sqlexception).  Instead of:

```
throws ex
```

you might try:

```
throw new RuntimeException(ex)
```

Further, I would recommend you be explicit about your transaction isolation.  Perhaps something like:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```