# Spring boot Service Layer Tranction not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions

i am trying to achieve spring boot Transaction service layer bit not able to achieve:

Here is my code

```
@Service
public class EmpService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo empRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeHealthInsuranceRepo healthRepo;
    
    @Transactional
    public void insertEmployee1(Employee employee,EmployeeHealthInsurance employeeHealthInsurance) {
        
            empRepo.save(employee);
            System.out.println(100/0);
            healthRepo.save(employeeHealthInsurance);
        
    
    
    }
    
    
    public void insertEmployee(Employee employee,EmployeeHealthInsurance employeeHealthInsurance) {
        insertEmployee1(employee,employeeHealthInsurance);

        }
}
```

i am expecting roll back if any error occuer from database or any code level

Comment: Can you show some related logs?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125837/why-does-transaction-roll-back-on-runtimeexception-but-not-sqlexception

Comment: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at com.example.transation.service.EmpService.insertEmployee1(EmpService.java:30)

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens when you call `insertEmployee1(...)` from `insertEmployee(...)`

The `@Transactional` annotation does not extend to the `insertEmployee(...)` method.

Try adding `@Transactional` above `insertEmployee(...)` for it to be transactional too.

Hope it helps.